# Bus tickets in Krakow

Tags: tickets, public-transport, buses, poland, krakow

I'll stay in Krakow for a few days next month and my hotel is a bit far from my work place.

I plan to use the buses but it looks uncertain to me, from what I have found that some bus stops are equipped with tickets machines, but I do not know which ones. I have also seen that a company (MPK) seems to provide tickets for the area, but I'm not sure it's compatible with the regular buses.

Is there a way to pre-order tickets or points to buy it by cash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a [tourist info website](http://www.krakow-info.com/transpor.htm):

> One-way ticket for a municipal bus or a streetcar (tram) is 4.6 zloty (an equivalent of roughly one euro). You can buy it at many newsstands and from ticket machines at downtown stops and in some buses and tram cars. Drivers sell 90-minute tickets worth six zlotys. Immediately after boarding you should put the ticket yourself through the ticket puncher and keep it till you reach your destination.

Apparently, you can easily buy tickets in the city centre. Buses that are equipped with ticket machines are marked with large “A” sign above the entrance.

If there is no ticket machine on board you can buy the 4 zł ticket from the driver but you have to pay him with exact change (driver will not accept a higher amount than the ticket price). If buying a ticket after mounting the vehicle try to be fast. Ticket inspectors are fairly common.

Comment: I like your answer however saying that ticket inspections in Kraków are fairly common is a big overstatement. In fact there are very uncommon and the average tourist would have to be very unlucky to have their ticket inspected. Out of my over 100 public transport rides in Kraków none of them ended in a ticket inspection.

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays you can buy a ticket in virtually every bus or tram (just be sure to enter the first coach). Be aware that some of them only accept credit cards, some only coins and finally there are some that accept any payment.

You can also buy tickets through several applications, I'm normally using [SkyCash](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skycash.beta) - you have to provide your credit card number in advance and create an account, then you can buy your ticket when entering the bus (just remember that you have to be on-line to do that).